# How to write "non-assert" debugging code in rust

Tags: debugging, rust, assertion

I have two (I hope) equivalent functions like:

```
fn slow_summary(foo: &Foo) -> Bar
fn fast_summary(foo: Foo) -> Bar
```

I want to add a debug_assert statement at the call-site that the fast summary gives the same result as the slow summary. Eg.

```
fn bar(foo: Foo) -> Baz {
  let summary = fast_summary(foo);
  debug_assert_eq!(summary, slow_summary(&foo));
  baz(summary)
}
```

But I can't do this because `foo` has already been consumed by the call to `fast_summary` (`Foo` is not an instance of `Clone` or `Copy`. I could make it `Clone` and then `clone` it but that's still introducing unnecessary runtime debt and also makes the code look uglier). Ideally, I'd call `slow_summary` *first*. And *then* call `fast_summary`, but how do I do this while still making sure `slow_summary` is only called when debug-assertions are turned on?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use [conditional compilation](https://doc.rust-lang.org/reference/conditional-compilation.html) with the `debug_assertions` condition:

```rs
fn bar(foo: Foo) -> Baz {
    let calculated_slow_summary: Bar;
    #[cfg(debug_assertions)]
    {
        calculated_slow_summary = slow_summary(&foo);   
    }
    let summary = fast_summary(foo);
    debug_assert_eq!(summary, calculated_slow_summary);
    baz(summary)
}
```